# Can i execute a single query on 2 database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am using php and mysql.

i have a question, lets say, I have a userid column in users table under database A, and userid column in purchases table under database B.

Can I execute a single query, using innerjoin, to get value from 2 databases? Or I must use multiple queries?

Oh ya, if let say, i have this variable:

```
$conn // connect to database A
```

Can i create another variable to connect database B before mysql_close()??

Sorry for multiple questions here ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM database1.table1 t1, database2.table2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

from MySQL documentation

> You can refer to a table within the
>   default database as tbl_name, or as
>   db_name.tbl_name to specify a database
>   explicitly. You can refer to a column
>   as col_name, tbl_name.col_name, or
>   db_name.tbl_name.col_name. You need
>   not specify a tbl_name or
>   db_name.tbl_name prefix for a column
>   reference unless the reference would
>   be ambiguous. See Section 8.2.1,
>   “Identifier Qualifiers”, for examples
>   of ambiguity that require the more
>   explicit column reference forms.

Comment: how to connect 2 databases? I mean, in php, mysql_select_db, can i select 2 databases???? My 2 databases has different users and password

Comment: you just select one of the db, it doesn't change anything, just the db you have selected you wouldn't have to write `database1.table` but just `table`. For the record: you can even select a different database but you would have to write database name on all queries.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try. Give me 5 minutes to test a simple query

Comment: I must grant the privilleges to that user first?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `<databasename>.<tablename>` to access tables from specific database and then perform normal join.